# check if versioning enabled on sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: 2010, list, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that updates document libraries to make sure that versioning is enabled:

```
$list.EnableVersioning = $true
```

How can I check whether versioning is enabled before making the change, so that I don't keep updating the list unnecessarily? I tried the following, but the syntax is incorrect:

```
if (list.EnableVersioning -ne $true) { $list.EnableVersioning = $true }
```

Comment: Above code works if I remember to add the $ before list "($list..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If versioning on List is Enabled then perform changes:

```
  If ($list.EnableVersioning -eq $TRUE) 
  { 
     //perform changes

  }
```

Answer (score -2):

This works in my environment

if($list.EnableVersioning=$true)

Comment: This condition will assign $true to the EnableVersioning and evaluate to true regardless of the old value of EnableVersioning